# Хочу понять на что ругается IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java

```
package com.dmdev.task;
public class Task134 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Спасибо! Вы ввели число " + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'Scanner'

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'Scanner'

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'nextInt()'

Comment: Импортируйте модуль **Scanner**

Comment: Могу Вас попросить перефразировать Ваше сообщение? Дело в том, что я буквально сегодня приобрёл свой первый курс по java. Возможно по этому слово "импортировать" у меня в голове не связанно с каким либо конкретным действием.

Comment: Ниже уже ответ написали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сделать импорт Scanner-а и всё:

```
import java.util.Scanner;// импортируем сканнер

public class Task134 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Спасибо! Вы ввели число " + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).